# Where can I find a longitudinal survey that includes sociographic data, including religion affiliation, over a long period?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, demographics

Where can I find a population longitudinal survey that would include the following data on the *same individuals* over a long period (5+ years, higher frequency is preferable)?

- Basic demographics (age, sex, marital status)
- Religious affiliation
- Geographical location (the higher resolution—the better; city-level is very good)
- Income and other economic data

I would be glad to hear suggestions that do not exactly fit this description.

As for the country, the US is preferable, but other countries are equally accepted.

At the moment, I've found the following ones:

- [Association of Religion Data Archives (ARDA)](http://www.thearda.com/Archive/Browse.asp) (though I didn't yet find out which of the surveys fit my needs)
- [Marital Instability over the Life Course](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/3812)
- [Panel Study of Income Dynamics](http://psidonline.isr.umich.edu/default.aspx)
- [Labour Force Survey Five-Quarter Longitudinal Dataset, January 2012 - March 2013](http://discover.ukdataservice.ac.uk/catalogue/?sn=7279)

There're much more, but maybe you could suggest the most suitable one?

***Update***

Links from the answers:

- [General Social Survey (GSS)](http://www3.norc.org/GSS+Website/)
- [American National Election Studies (ANES)](http://www.electionstudies.org/index.htm)
- [National Longitudinal Study of Adolescent Health (Add Health), 1994-2008 (ICPSR 21600)](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/21600)

Comment: i don't think many us-funded surveys have religious affiliation.. but also check out the gss and the anes

Comment: You could also try [Add Health](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/21600). As for your search terms, instead of saying over a long period, you should be saying longitudinal **panel** survey while avoiding longitudinal cross-section surveys.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some additional studies that may be useful:

**Most likely meets most or all of your criteria:**

- [Americans' Changing Lives: Waves I, II, III, and IV, 1986, 1989, 1994, and 2002 (ICPSR 04690)](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACDA/studies/04690)

**May meet some of your criteria:**

- You mentioned ARDA studies already, but [the National Study of Youth and Religion (3 separate waves)](http://www.thearda.com/Archive/Browse_a.asp#N) may be helpful.